# Why is $T\colon X \to Y$ a homeomorphism?

Tags: normed-spaces

I am reading through a paper in which the following is stated without proof:

> If $X$ is a normed space with norm $\| \cdot\|_X$ such that every norm on $X$ is equivalent to $\| \cdot\|_X$ then the bijective linear map $T\colon X \to Y$ where $Y$ is a normed space with norm $\|\cdot\|_Y$, is a homeomorphism.

I can not seem to see why this is true. Can somebody please show me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push the norm $\|\cdot \|_Y$ back to $X$ using the bijection $T$. That is, defining a norm on $X$ by $\|x\|_{T}:=\|Tx\|_Y$. Then using the assumption that every norm on $X$ is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_X$ to obtain $$c_1\|x\|_X\leq \|x\|_T=\|Tx\|_Y\leq c_2\|x\|_X$$ for some non-zero constants $c_1,c_2$, this implies that $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are continuous.

Comment: Thank you! :). I can see how this would imply that $T$ is continuous, (since it's linear and bounded), but how do we deduce that $T^{-1}$ is also continuous?

Comment: @DJS $T$ is bounded below. $c_1\|x\|_X\leq \|Tx\|_Y$ is equivalent to $\|T^{-1}y\|_X\leq \frac{1}{c_1}\|y\|_Y$

Answer (score 0):

As $T$ is bijective and linear, $\|\cdot\|_Y$ induces a norm on $X$. By assumption, this norm is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_X$, hence induces the given topology on $X$. So the topologies on $X$ and $Y$ are "the same" via $T$.